# Can not build LibAdblockPlus

Tags: python

I am using Windows 10 x64 OS
I downloaded the master branch of libadblockplus from the link below:
​https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus

I have built V8 (The javascript library from google which is required for Libadblockplus). The path for the headers files and binary files of my V8 built are as follows, respectively:

```
C:\V-eight\v8\include
```

and

```
C:\V-eight\v8\out.gn\x64.release\obj
```

I have set my path in environment variables such that if I do "where python" at the command for example C:>where python then I get the following response:

```
C:\V-eight\depot_tools\python.bat
```

I have set the environment variable "GYP_DEFINES" as below:
GYP_DEFINES=C:\V-eight\v8

I ran the createsolution.bat from the path as below:
C:\V-eight\libadblockplus>createsolution.bat

I am getting the following error:

> File
>   "C:\V-eight\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 957, in _execute_child startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The
>   system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Can anyone please help me to build  LibadblockPlus

Comment: yes. I installed VS 2017

Comment: I have VS professional  2017 version 15.8.3